# Upload a file from aws s3 to linux server directly with private key

Tags: go, amazon-s3

There are some larger size files in AWS S3. I need to copy those files to a remote server.

I've tried with the below code, but I'm not able to transfer the file. Is this right way or I need to do in any other ways.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/tmc/scp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "devtools/objectstorage"
    "log"
    "os"
)


func main() {
    var osSecretKey = "secret-key"
    var osAccessKeyID = "access-key"
    var osRegion = "region"
    var osUrl = "url"
    var osBucketName = "bucket"

    accpusr := "username"
    accphost := "server"
    sshport := "22"
    scpDestinationPath := "/destination/path"

    s3Config := objectstorage.S3Config{
        AccessKeyID:     osAccessKeyID,
        SecretAccessKey: osSecretKey,
        Region:          osRegion,
        Bucket:          osBucketName,
        URL:             osUrl,
    }
    var s3FileName = "sample.txt"
    var storage, err = objectstorage.New(s3Config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to create s3 session", err)
    }
    dlObj, err := storage.Download(s3FileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to download s3 file", err)
    }
    log.Println("downloaded object")
    err = Send(accpusr, accphost, sshport, scpDestinationPath, s3FileName, *dlObj.ContentLength, dlObj.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to copy file", err)
    }
    log.Println("file copied successfully")
}

func Send(remoteUser, remoteHost, remoteSSHPort, remoteFolder, remoteFileName string, size int64, r io.Reader) error {

    session, err := connect(remoteUser, remoteHost, remoteSSHPort)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer session.Close()
    err = scp.Copy(size, os.FileMode.Perm(0770), remoteFileName, r, remoteFolder, session)
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error sending file: %s", err.Error())
        return errors.New(errMsg)
    }
    return nil
}

func connect(remoteUser string, remoteHost string, remoteSSHPort string) (*ssh.Session, error) {
    //retrieve public key from private key
    key, err := retrieveKey()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var sshConfig ssh.Config
    sshConfig.SetDefaults()
    sshConfig.Ciphers = append(sshConfig.Ciphers, "aes256-cbc")
    // Define the Client Config as:
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        Config: sshConfig,
        User:   remoteUser,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeys(key),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", remoteHost, remoteSSHPort), config)
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error connecting to client: %s", err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New(errMsg)
    }

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error creating session: %s", err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New(errMsg)
    }
    return session, nil
}

func retrieveKey() (key ssh.Signer, err error) {

    scpCert := ""
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s", scpCert))
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error retrieving key: %s", err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New(errMsg)
    }
    key, err = ssh.ParsePrivateKey(buf)
    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("Error parsing key: %s", err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New(errMsg)
    }
    return key, nil
}
```

`objectstorage.New` will return `aws s3 session`.

`storage.Download` will return `s3.GetObjectOutput`.